# Conditional expectation of random vector given low-rank linear transform

Tags: linear-model, conditional-expectation

Given the random vector
$$
\mathbf{h} = \left(\begin{matrix} \mu \\ \varepsilon_1 \\ \varepsilon_2 \end{matrix} \right) \thicksim  \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_\mathbf{h})
$$
and the low-rank transform:
$$
\mathbf{P} =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
it's easy to show that
$$
\mathbf{P}\mathbf{h} = \left( \begin{matrix}\mu + \varepsilon_1 \\ \mu + \varepsilon_2 \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix}\right) = \mathbf{x} \thicksim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma_x})
$$
with
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma_x} = \mathbf{P\Sigma_\mathbf{h}P}^T
$$

My question is how to compute the expectation of $\mathbf{h}$ given $\mathbf{x}$. I'm lead to believe that

$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{h}|\mathbf{x}] = \mathbf{\Sigma_h}\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}_\mathbf{x}^{-1}\mathbf{x}
$$

but I can't figure out how to derive that result. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that 
$$
\mathbb{E}_\mathbf{h}[\mathbf{h}|\mathbf{x}] = \mathbf{Mx}
$$
for some $\mathbf{M}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{cov}(\mathbf{h}, \mathbf{x}) &= \mathrm{cov}(\mathbf{h}, \mathbf{x}) \\
\mathrm{cov}(\mathbf{h}, \mathbf{Ph}) &= \mathrm{cov}(\mathbb{E}_\mathbf{h}[\mathbf{h}|\mathbf{x}], \mathbf{x})\\
\mathrm{cov}(\mathbf{h}, \mathbf{h})\mathbf{P}^T &= \mathrm{cov}(\mathbf{Mx}, \mathbf{x}) \\
&= \mathbf{M}\mathrm{cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}) \\
\mathbf{\Sigma_h}\mathbf{P}^T &= \mathbf{M}\mathbf{\Sigma_x} \\
\mathbf{\Sigma_h}\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}_\mathbf{x}^{-1} &= \mathbf{M} \\
\end{align}
$$

The linearity assumption can be made because all distributions are Gaussian.